# Create Unit Test for a function in C# that uses SecretClient.GetSecret function

Tags: c#, azure, moq

I have a good knowledge of Java but I am new to C#.

I am facing difficulty while writing unit test for the following example code:

```
public static IDictionary<string, string> GetVaultSecretsDictionary(Uri keyVaultUrl, ChainedTokenCredential azureChainedCredential, string[] secretNames)
{
    var client = new SecretClient(keyVaultUrl, azureChainedCredential);
    var vaultSecrets = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var secretName in secretNames) {
        Response<KeyVaultSecret> responseKeyVaultSecret = client.GetSecret(secretName);
        var secretValue = responseKeyVaultSecret.Value.Value;
        vaultSecrets.Add(secretName, secretValue);
    }
    return vaultSecrets;
}
```

I want to write unit test for the above function, but I do not know how can I mock SecretClient and then inject it in similar way we use **InjectMock** in Java. Plus, in order to get the **responseKeyVaultSecret** value, a request is also sent to the URL, I do not how can I acheive the ***GetSecret***  to return the response mock value.

I have look for examples and tutorials but the were not fruitful for me.

**Note**: No changes can be made within the above function.

Comment: Does the below answer helps your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the client is generated in the body of the method, so you don't really have an option to mock it. You would neet to pass it to the method in order to achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 6):

As Pawel told in the answer above, you will have to pass `SecretClient` in your method. Then, Mock it in your test class and pass it to be used for Unit Testing. For example, you can Mock it using [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart):

Create a test client instance using Moq:

```
Mock<SecretClient> clientMock = new Mock<SecretClient>();
clientMock.Setup(c => c.GetSecret(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .Returns(...);

clientMock.Setup(c => c.GetSecretAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(...);

SecretClient secretClient = clientMock.Object;
```

Then, pass `clientMock.Object` as a parameter of type `SecretClient` in `GetVaultSecretsDictionary` method or the class's constructor and then remove `var client = new SecretClient(keyVaultUrl, azureChainedCredential);` and use that input parameter instead.

Check out this detailed tutorial for assistance: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/unit-testing-and-mocking/

Comment: Then, you cannot mock it AFAIK. The instances initialized inside the function cannot be mocked.